# Quadratic congruence with odd prime modulus

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My answer in this question $$n^2 = 7\mod9$$is $$n = 4 + 9c$$ and $$n = 5 + 9c$$ where c belongs to Integes... through observation but I cannot get the actual solution...any clue?

Comment: $9$ is a very small number ... "by observation" is as good as any method for proving things modulo $9$.

Comment: You could also test $n = -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ to further reduce the number of cases.

Comment: We need to test for $1\le n\le \dfrac92$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$n^2\equiv 7\mod 9\equiv 16\mod 9$$ so $$(n-4)(n+4)\equiv 0 \mod 9$$